# How to reason about the probability that a conditional probability is large?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I need to reason about the probability that a conditional probability is large, and I'm not sure where to start. Specifically, let $E$ be an event, and $Z$ be a random variable. Let 
$$
\mathcal A=\{z \in \operatorname{support}(Z) : \Pr(E|Z=z)\geq \alpha\}.
$$
I want to reason about $\Pr(Z \in \mathcal A)$.

In sloppier notation:
$$
\Pr(Z:\Pr(E|Z) \geq \alpha).
$$

Is there a name for this kind of expression, any rules for rewriting it in a different form, or general tricks for dealing with an expression of this form?

Comment: in first place the notation $Z\in\mathcal A$ is not correct because $\mathcal A$ belongs to the domain of $Z$, not to it image. That is: you must change the part of $z\in\mathrm{support}(Z)$ by $z\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, assuming that the codomain of $Z$ is $\Bbb R$

Comment: And "reason about" is too vague.  Can you post an actual *problem* that requires computation?

Comment: What is this: $ Pr(Z:\Pr(E|Z) \geq \alpha)$? I would rather write:$Pr(Pr(E|Z) \geq \alpha); which would be meaningful.

Comment: @zoli The form you have doesn't make it clear what each of the probability statements is over - is the inner or outer over E or Z (or some other random quantities)? I agree though that what you wrote works.

Comment: @Masacroso $z \in \mathbb R^n$, not $\mathbb R$. I don't see the issue with what I wrote, since support(Z) is a set, in this case $\mathbb R^n$, and so writing z in support(Z) is the same as z in $\mathbb R^n$ without having to talk about z being a vector (I don't think that's relevant).

Comment: because $Z=z$ is a shorthand for $Z(\omega)=z$, that is, $\omega$ is in $\Bbb R^n$, not $z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enlighten the meaning of
$$Pr(Pr(E|Z) \geq \alpha)$$ let' see an example.

Let $$\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$$

with $P(\{1\})=\frac12$ and $P(\{i\})=\frac16$ for $i=2,3,4$ and $E=\{2,3\}$, and let $Z(\omega)=u$ for $\omega\in \{1,2\}$ and $v$ for the rest, finally let $\alpha=\frac13$.

Now $Pr(E\mid Z)$ is a random variable:

$$Pr(E \mid Z)(\omega)=$$
$$=\frac{Pr(E\cap \{\omega\})}{Pr(\{\omega\})}=$$
$$=
\begin{cases}
0,&\text{ if }& \omega=1,4\\
1,&\text{ if }& \omega=2,3
\end{cases}.$$

So
$$Pr(Pr(E\mid Z)>\alpha)=\frac13.$$